# Sending hex command via serial using python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, serial-port

I am experiencing some problems trying to send the hex command FF AA 69 88 B5 via serial (ttyUSB0) using python function serial.write

I am trying to send a command to my sensor (IMU) connected via UART FTDI to USB using serial in python.
The steps I followed areis the following:

1. Sensor I/F is an UART (RX/TX)
2. It is connected to an FTDI to the USB
   port of a raspberry py 4
3. As soon as I connect it, it is correclty
   attached to /dev/ttyUSB0, I can see the bynary data flowing from the
   sensor just by

`xxd -b < /dev/ttyUSB0`

So the sensor is alive and running correctly in connected with raspberry

I am able to read it from python3 using serial and unpacking data with struct (see an example reading the first element of a quaternion): It works perfectly!

```
import serial
import struct
imu=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')
data=imu.read_until(b'\x59')
Q0L=imu.read(1)
Q0H=imu.read(1)
sumcheck=imu.read(1)
Q0 = struct.unpack("<h", Q0L + Q0H)[0] / 32768.0
print("Quaternion 0 = "+ str(Q0))
```

Now I want to send commands (calibrate it or change frequency)
In the documentation it provides the hex code for those commands. In order to see the results easily I just tried to change data update frequency:

1. FF AA 69 88 B5 (Unlock)
2. FF AA 03 07 00 (07 means 20HZ)
3. FF AA 00 00 00 (Save Config)

Again, I use first the terminal and I send those commands using a simple echo:

```
echo -e "\xff\xaa\x69\x88\xb5" > /dev/ttyUSB0
echo -e "\xff\xaa\x03\x07\x00" > /dev/ttyUSB0
echo -e "\xff\xaa\x00\x00\x00" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

And it works pefectly (if I change the frequency I can see it in the parser I have implemented in python.

No I want to send those commands in the python script, so I tried serial write command:

```
imu.write(b'\xff\xaa\x69\x88\xb5')
imu.write(b'\xff\xaa\x03\x07\x00')
imu.write(b'\xff\xaa\x00\x00\x00')
```

But I get no effect, no answer from the sensor.
For sure I am using serial write wrongly.
Any clue?

Thanks so much for the support!!

Guillermo

Comment: Perhaps when you use `echo`, there is a delay between each command you send and this is missing in the Python code. Try adding a `time.sleep(0.5)` between each write, for example. Also, the echo will add `\n` to the end of each command.

Comment: Thanks! at the end the problem was trying to send byte string instead of a byte array in python. It shows a different behaviour in python w.r.t. a simple echo.